# Excel VBA method ROUND is incorrect

Tags: excel, rounding, vba

```
Public Function foo()
Dim x As Double, y As Double, z As Double

x = 1.26
y = 3.175
z = Round(x + y, 2)

foo = z
End Function
```

Running Excel 2007 on Windows 7. This function returns 4.43 into a cell with =foo() which is annoying as I want 4.44. I found some documentation claiming VBA ROUND uses even rounding but here the last digit is odd. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the Worksheet Round Function instead of VBA's built-in one

```
Public Function foo2()
    Dim x As Double, y As Double, z As Double

    x = 1.26
    y = 3.175
    z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(x + y, 2)

    foo2 = z
End Function
```

foo2 will result in `4.44` (tested on my machine). I don't know if this would affect performance at all.

Comment: Yes that works ... but why on Earth would they make the VBA version of ROUND different from the Worksheet one?

Comment: VBA Round uses Bankers rounding: see for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding.aspx for an explanation of Bankers Rounding and why it is often a good rounding method.

Comment: For interest, `Z = CDbl(Format(x + Y, "0.00"))` (inspired by the Eric Lippert blog) takes 1.36s for a million iterations compared with 1.44s for `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(x + y, 2)`. A performance hit for using worksheet functions is to be expected.

Comment: @grahamj42 Thanks for confirming the performance hit. I figured that would be the case.

Comment: @guitarthrower Can you explain how "Bankers rounding" gives 4.43 in my example?

Comment: @TheMathemagician I didn't post the link, but after a quick skim it seems to be saying that if you have a series of numbers ending with a 5 (i.e. 1.675, 1.895, 1.985, 1.235) then bankers rounding will change them to 1.68 (up), 1.89 (down), 1.99 (up), 1.23 (down) and provide a closer result than rounding all the items up. In your situation banker's rounding won't matter since you only have 1 number ending in 5 that is being rounded.

Comment: @guitarthrower You misunderstood my question, I was being sarcastic re. Excel. I know what banker's rounding is (no-one in banking uses it) but it should round to 4.24 not 4.23. So even by their own mad rules it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use decimal types to accomplish this which uses integer based arithmetic as opposed to floating point based.

Excel doesn't have a native data type for this, so you have to use a `Variant` and then convert to a decimal using the `CDec` function.

```
Public Function foo()
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, z As Variant

    x = CDec(1.26)
    y = CDec(3.175)
    z = Round(x + y, 2)

    foo = z
End Function
```

Comment: Yes although if you change 3.175 to 3.165 you'll find it rounds 4.425 to 4.42 which is the 'even' rounding method (and precisely what no-one actually wants).

Answer (score 0):

While `Excel.WorksheetFunction.Round` does perform correct 4/5 rounding, it is terribly slow and, of course, requires Excel to be installed.

For fast and precise rounding of any value - up, down, 4/5, Banker's, significant digits, Base 2 or Base 10, and more - go to my project [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).